# How to create a bar graph to visually represent two variables, while keeping the same color for the x-axis variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, legend

For example, here is a data.

```
Genotype=c("A","A","B","B","C","C","A","A","B","B","C","C")
Season=c("2022","2023","2022","2023","2022","2023","2022","2023","2022","2023","2022","2023")
Type=c("I","I","I","I","I","I","II","II","II","II","II","II")
Yield=c(100,120,110,80,60,90,100,100,170,80,30,90)
dataA= data.frame(Genotype, Season, Type, Yield)
```

And I created a bar graph

```
ggplot(data=dataA, aes(x=Genotype, y=Yield, fill=Genotype, group1=Season, color=Season))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge", width= 0.7, size=1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkred","blue","grey")) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black","orange")) +
  labs(x="Genotype", y="Yield") +
  theme_classic(base_size=18, base_family="serif") +
  theme(legend.position="right",
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.key=element_rect(color="white", fill="white"),
        legend.text=element_text(family="serif", face="plain",
                                 size=15, color="black"),
        legend.background= element_rect(fill="white"),
        axis.line = element_line(linewidth = 0.5, colour="black"))+
windows(width=7, height=5)
```

[image]

However, my intention is to display only the legend for the season. Within each genotype, I aim to maintain consistent colors while differentiating the two bars, perhaps using lines, dashes, or other visual distinctions. For example, like below, or other way to distinguish two bars between two seasons.

[image]

Could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your desired output is. What do you want to do with the Type variable? you seem to have more than one observation per bar so it's not clear how that should be display. You only want a legend for the year but you still want the different genotypes to be different colors?

Comment: @MrFlick I updated my questions. I just want to provide the genotype with the same color and divide seasons by lines or dashed or something. Also want to show legend for season. Thanks

Comment: From a data visualisation perspective, the colors don't add anything here. The viewer can already see the genotype by the x axis. You are making plotting harder by trying to make it look unnecessarily garish and less professional. Why not simply make the bars gray and white according to season?

Comment: @AllanCameron This is because I have another graph as regression and each point is for genotype, and I would like to keep the same color on genotype variables between two graphs. But the code you provided is perfect to me!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ggpattern`, you can do:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpattern)

dataA %>%
  group_by(Season, Genotype) %>%
  summarise(Yield = sum(Yield), .groups = "drop") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Genotype, Yield, fill = Genotype, pattern = Season,
             pattern_type = Season)) +
  geom_col_pattern(position = "dodge", pattern_fill = "black", color = "black",
                   pattern_angle = 45, pattern_spacing = 0.02,
                   pattern_color = "black") +
  scale_pattern_type_manual(NULL, values = c("none", "stripe")) +
  scale_pattern_manual(NULL, values = c("none", "stripe")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkred", "blue", "grey"), guide = "none") +
  theme_classic(base_size=18, base_family="serif") +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(color = "white", fill = "white"),
        legend.text = element_text(color = "black"),
        axis.line = element_line(linewidth = 0.5, colour = "black"))
```

[image]

Note that it's not clear how you want to deal with the `Type` variable. Presumably, since this is not referenced on your initial plot, you want the two types stacked, which I have done here by summing them prior to plotting.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!!!